# How to write this domain notation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

For $y=1/x^3$ the domain is $\{x\mid x\neq  3\}$. In notation, would we write the domain as: $(3, +\infty]$ or $[4, \infty)$? Perhaps my inclusive brackets are not right but more so focused on if we would put 3 exclusive or 4?

CORRECTION: I meant to write y=1/(x-3) and yes I realize my domain notation was backwards/incorrect.

Comment: The question is reasonable... and what the heck does the tag "domain theory" refer to?

Comment: Is it $x-3$? Because it looks like it is.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x\neq 3\}=(-\infty,3)\cup(3,\infty).$$

Comment: Why would we include 3? Doesnt a parenthesis indicate it is included. If you didnt see I updated my question I had the function written wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})(x \neq 3 \;\leftrightarrow\; x < 3 \;\mathrm{or} \;x > 3).$$

Hence: $$\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \neq 3\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}:x < 3\;\mathrm{or} \;x > 3\}.$$

But the right-hand side above can be rewritten like so:

$$\mathrm{RHS} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}:x<3\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{R}:x>3\} = (-\infty,3) \cup (3,\infty).$$

Hence:

$$\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \neq 3\} = (-\infty,3) \cup (3,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

> For $y=1/x^3$ the domain is $\{x\mid x\neq  3\}$. In notation, would we write the domain as: $(3, +\infty]$ or $[4, \infty)$? Perhaps my inclusive brackets are not right but more so focused on if we would put 3 exclusive or 4?

$(3; +\infty) = \{x\in\Bbb R\mid x< 3\}$

$[4; \infty)= \{x\in\Bbb R\mid x\leq 4\}$

Neither is correct, though the first is somewhat closer.  (Note $3.5\neq 3$ and such.)

You wish to express $\{x\mid x<3~\lor~3<x\}$, which is the union $(-\infty;3)\cup(3;+\infty)$.

Also written as $\Bbb R\setminus\{3\}$.

---

PS: For $y=1/x^3$ the domain is $\{x\in \Bbb R\mid x\neq 0\}$.   Are you sure you did not mean $y=1/(x-3)$?

Comment: YES, someone literally edited my question essentially making it a different question. I meant to ask exactly what you confirmed... y=1/x-3) how would we write the domain? Also, I know my suggested domain notation was backwards LOL...